# Android In-App Purchase version 3 billing Issue not allowing more than 20 SKUs?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, in-app

I have implemented the In-App purchase in my app using version 3 billing API . According to the .aidl file , this API allow only 20 SKU items from the play store. But i have 24 items listed there. When i list all the 24 items, it throws the Developer Error . But when i list less than 20 items , i could able to connect. Is there any solution to overcome this . ?

I google it and got a patch for IabHelper.java. But no use. Can anyone help me here.. ? and sorry for my poor english.

Thank you ,

Answer (score 0):

It seems such issue was fixed in OpenIAB (it's based on improved IabHelper).

Probably these snippet could help: [IabHelper](https://github.com/oorlov/OpenIAB/blob/master/library/src/org/onepf/oms/appstore/googleUtils/IabHelper.java#L941)